# Datatablet JS Exportar com Multilinhas

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Opa,

Numa mesma celula do datatable podem haver várias linhas, sendo que a função `buttons`para exportar do datatable  não reconhece a tag `<Br>`, estou tentando usar o `columns` e o `render` desta forma, apenas para teste, onde ele deve trocar a `,` por `<br>`. O datatable aparece, mas, os botões não.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {


   ///Se adicionar botões exportar não aparecem
        columns: [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    return data.split(", ").join("<br/>");
                }
            }
        ],
   ///Se adicionar botões exportar não aparecem


    lengthChange: false,
    buttons: [


        {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: 'Copiar'
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            text: 'Imprimir',
            message: '<?php echo $TextoArquivoExport;?>',
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
             title: '<?php echo $NomeArquivoExport;?>'
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'LEGAL',
             fieldSeparator: '\t',
             message: '<?php echo $TextoArquivoExport;?>',
            title: '<?php echo $NomeArquivoExport;?>',
                exportOptions: {
                    stripNewlines: false
                }
        },
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: 'Exibir/Ocultar Coluna'
        }

    ],

    language: {
        buttons: {
            copyTitle: 'Informações do relatório copiadas',
            copyKeys: 'Foram copiados <i>ctrl</i> ou <i>\u2318</i> + <i>C</i> registros. <br><br>Por favor, pressione o botão ESC para sair.',
            copySuccess: {
                _: '%d registros copiados',
                1: '1 linha copiada'
            }
        }
    }

} );
```

O objetivo em questão é que seja realizada a substituição da `,` pelo `<br>`e que haja a quebra de linha.
Baseado no `columns`e no `render`:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Possível solução retirada de:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791577/how-can-i-implement-new-line-in-a-column-datatables

Answer (score 0):

Subtitua a linha:

```
{
  render: function(data, type, row){
  return data.split(", ").join("<br/>");
}
```

Por,

```
{ null,
  render: function(data, type, row){
  return data.split(", ").join("<br/>");
}
```

O datatables ele exige que tu faça uma identificação na coluna, caso tu não queira como é o caso você necessita colocar null e depois executar o render.
Acho que era isso :D

Comment: Sem sucesso amigão, ocorre o mesmo, ao editar o que informou, os botões de exportar não aparecem. Preciso exatamente que eles apareçam e no exportar as quebras de linha também funcionem. Abraço